# Need help proving that the set of natural numbers is transitive.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The problem reads: Prove that $\mathbb{N}$ is transitive.

With the definition of a transitive set that im using is $\forall x \in X$, $x \subset X$.

I cant help but feel that i'm missing something. Any help/advice is greatly appreciated. This is what i have so far:

Let $A$ be the set of all transitive natural numbers

$n \in A$, iff $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $x \subset n$, $\forall x \in n$

$ 0 \in A $

Suppose $n \in A$, consider $n^+ = n \cup$ {n}

if $x \in n^+$, then $x \in n$ or $x=n$

If $x \in n$, then $x \subset n \subset n^+$

or

If $x=n$, then $x \subset n^+$

It follows that every element of $n^+$ is a subset of $n^+$

$n^+ \in A$

By induction $A=\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathbb{N}$? (No, seriously; to do this problem, you need to know both what "transitive" means, and also exactly what "$\mathbb{N}$" is). And what is the definition of $n$?

Comment: Note that assuming everything you did were correct, and you have proven that "the set of all transitive natural numbers" is equal to $\mathbb{N}$, then what you have proven is that each natural number is transitive. But that is **not** what you are trying to prove. You are trying to prove that the set $\mathbb{N}$ is transitive, not that each element of the set is transitive.

Comment: Well I'm using the peano axioms that define the natural numbers ( $\mathbb{N}$).  And a transitive set has the property that it includes "$\subset$" everything that it contains "$\in$". I hope that helps.

Comment: The Peano axioms don't define $\mathbb{N}$ inside of set theory; if you have a set, then the set must be *constructed* in some way, within your set theory. Once you construct it, then the Peano axioms become *theorems* about your constructed set. However, what you are trying to prove here is a *set-theoretic* property of the set you have *constructed*, so you cannot derive it from the Peano axioms; the Peano axioms assume you already have a set and a function, and do not care about what the set actually is. So you cannot just be "using the Peano axioms".

Comment: Prove "If n in N, then  n subset N" by induction on N.